Divided Differences Proof- Using Mathematical Induction
I've recently started studying Numerical Analysis and learned about divided differences. My professor defined it as follows.
Let $f$ be a function and $x_0,...,x_n$ be $n+1$ different nodes in the domain of $f$. The divided differences of $f$ can be defined recursively as follows:
$\fbox{Divided differences of order zero}$
$$f[x_j] := f(x_j), \ j=0,...,n$$
$\fbox{Divided differences of order one}$
$$F[x_j,x_{j+1}] := \frac{f[x_{j+1}]-f[x_j]}{x_{j+1}-x_j}=\frac{f(x_{j+1})-f(x_j)}{x_{j+1}-x_j}, \ j=0,...,n-1.$$
$\fbox{Divided differences of order k}$
$$f[x_j,...,x_{j+k}]:= \frac{f[x_{j+1},...,x_{j+k}]-f[x_j,...,x_{j+k-1}]}{x_{j+k}-x_j}.$$
Then, my professor introduced the following lemma. The divided differences satisfy the following relation
$$f[x_j,...,x_{j+k}] = \sum_{l=j}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)},$$
$j=0,...,n-k$ and $k=1,...,n.$
However my professor did not prove this. He left it as an exercise and suggested using induction in k.
I struggled to prove lemma. Naturally, I searched for a proof online but I found very little information, and what I found was not that good. Therefore, I'm writing this question to leave a good proof of this lemma or, at least, what I think is a good proof.
Let us now prove this lemma using Mathematical Induction in k.
For $k=1$, we have that
$$f[x_j,x_{j+1}] \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{f(x_{j+1})-f(x_j)}{x_{j+1}-x_j}= \frac{f(x_{j+1})}{x_{j+1}-x_j} + \frac{f(x_j)}{x_j-x_{j+1}}=  \sum_{l=j}^{j+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+1} (x_l - x_m)}.$$
Let $k > 1$.
Let us assume the result true for $k$ and prove the result for $k+1$.
$$f[x_j,...,x_{j+k+1}] \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{f[x_{j+1},...,x_{j+k+1}]-f[x_j,...,x_{j+k}]}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \stackrel{I.H.}{=}$$
$$\stackrel{I.H.}{=} \frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \left [ \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)} -  \sum_{l=j}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)} \right].$$
The term $l=j+k+1$ only appears in $ \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)}.$
The term $l=j$ only appears in $\sum_{l=j}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)}.$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \left[ \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)} -  \sum_{l=j}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)} \right]=$$
$$= \frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \left[ \frac{f(x_{j+k+1})}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq j+k+1}^{j+k+1} (x_{j+k+1}-x_m)} + \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)} -  \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)} - \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k} (x_j-x_m)}\right].$$
However,
$$\frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \cdot \frac{f(x_{j+k+1})}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq j+k+1}^{j+k+1} (x_{j+k+1} - x_m)} = \frac{f(x_{j+k+1})}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j+k+1}^{j+k+1} (x_{j+k+1}-x_j)}$$
and
$$- \frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \cdot \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k} (x_j - x_m)} = \frac{1}{x_j - x_{j+k+1}} \cdot \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k+1} (x_j-x_m)}= \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k+1} (x_j -x_m)}.$$
Furthermore,
$$ \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)} -  \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)}= \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \left[ \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1}(x_l-x_m)} - \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l-x_m)} \right]=$$
$$=\sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} f(x_l) \left[ \frac{1}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1}(x_l-x_m)} - \frac{1}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l-x_m)} \right]=\sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} f(x_l) \left[ \prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m} - {\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m}} \right]=$$
$$=\sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} f(x_l) \left[ \frac{x_l - x_j}{x_l-x_j} \cdot \prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m} - \frac{x_l-x_{j+k+1}}{x_l-x_{j+k+1}} \cdot \prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m} \right]=$$
$$=\sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} f(x_l) \left[ (x_l - x_j) \cdot \prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m} - (x_l-x_{j+k+1}) \cdot \prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{1}{x_l-x_m} \right]=$$
$$=\sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} f(x_l)  \cdot \prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{x_l -x_j -x_l + x_{j+k+1}}{x_l-x_m} =$$
$$= (x_{j+k+1}-x_j) \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{x_l-x_m}}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{x_{j+k+1}-x_j} \left[ \frac{f(x_{j+k+1})}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\ m \neq j+k+1}^{j+k+1} (x_{j+k+1}-x_m)} + \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j+1 \\m \neq l}^{j+k+1} (x_l - x_m)} -  \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)} - \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k} (x_j-x_m)}\right]=$$
$$= \frac{f(x_{j+k+1})}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j+k+1}^{j+k+1} (x_{j+k+1}-x_j)} + \sum_{l=j+1}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{x_l-x_m}} + \frac{f(x_j)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq j}^{j+k+1} (x_j -x_m)} =$$
$$=\sum_{l=j}^{j+k+1}  \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\ m \neq l}^{j+k+1} \frac{f(x_l)}{x_l-x_m}}.$$
$\therefore$ The result is valid for all $k \in \mathbb{N}. \blacksquare$
